# Select from entity where not in MyList<T>(field) using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have some code to check if my version field in DB is contained in any of item in `MyList<EntityPoco>`.

I want to know if there is a better way or simpler method to do this than what I already have:

```
List<Model.Job> jobs = mapperJobs.Map(dt).ToList();

bool itemExists = false;

foreach (Model.Job job in jobs)
{
    var result = db.Jobs.Where(a => (a.Version == job.Version));

    // If the item exists move on.
    if (result.Any())
    {
        itemExists = true;
        break;
    }

    // Else we need to insert a new record in the db 
    if (!itemExists)
    {
        db.Jobs.Add(job);
    }
} // ... db save changes after adding everything we want
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a join in EF to an in-memory collection, bout you can extract a list of values and use `Contains`:

```
var jobVersions = jobs.Select(job => job.Version).ToArray();
var result = db.Jobs.Where(a => jobVersions.Contains(a.Version));
```

Comment: One question I also want to have the list of jobs that were not in the database (my primary goal) so I can decide to ignore the row (since it is of no interest to me ) or insert the new data which is important to me.

Comment: Could you not just do `.Where(a => !jobVersions.Contains(...`?

Comment: That gives me the db results object. The end game is to get the list<Job> that is not in the db and then insert that record only. I am getting the db item, there is a reason I am doing this without using the update (if it  exists I don't want to update it - I want to throw it away) and if not the item in the list is mapped to myEntity and I can add t to the context.Job.AddRange(filteredjobs) .

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You might need to ask a follow-up question with more details.

Comment: my list came from a 3rd party xml import, there is a field that tells me what their software xml version is. While I will store it the first time I come across a unique value (to map my data back to xml sw version) - if it exists already in my db - I don't care about it at this point so I will skip it and I am just going to plug everything else in the tables.

Comment: So either get ALL jobs IDs from the DB and compare to your list or loop through your list and see if the job exists in the DB.

Comment: that was my foreach - so I guess there is not simple one/two liner to do it.. Thx..